# Why is moving a rectangle not consistent?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm pretty new to C# and i'm trying to make a simple program that allows to move a rectangle using input. The problem is when updating the position of a rectangle in C# the rectangle sometimes seems like it disappears for a very short time then reappears in its new location instead of moving consistently.

I'v done similar things using [p5.js](https://p5js.org/) and java (Jswing).

Here is the code i'v written

```
 public class WinFormsTest : Form
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
    Graphics graphics;
    Brush brush;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 80, 80);

    public WinFormsTest()
    {
       Draw();
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        Text = "HelloWold";
        Height = 800;
        Width = 800;

        timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        Invalidate();
        timer.Start();

    }
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        graphics = CreateGraphics();
        brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
        graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        Random rnd = new Random();
        graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
        rect.X++;
        rect.Y++;

    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.Run(new WinFormsTest());
    }
}
```

I would expect the rectangle to consistently move without sometimes disappearing and reappearing.

Comment: What is that: `timer.Interval = 1;` ? Are you perhaps a proud owner of one of the rarest, heretofore unseen monitors with a display refresh rate of 1000 Hz? ;-)

Comment: Ehhhhhh i'm sorry if it is wrong, but increasing the interval gives a very laggy feel so i though it would be normal to set it to its minimal value. How ever it still doesn't solve the issue completely as instead of the current problem i would get a laggy feel.

Comment: Your method is not correct : all the drawing must be done in Paint event

Comment: How that please? I would be really thankful to get a code example !

Comment: There are thousands of code examples around.. - But: Winforms doesn't support synchiing with the monitor, so there may always be some quirks.

Comment: @ŘenĞod: I have added a XAML example

Comment: Please post code that actually displays the issue; `rect.X++;` is not going to move the rectangle, so it's obviously not the code you've tested this with. There's also a *major* red flag in that you're never disposing the graphics object you've created - this is a big no-no. Use `using` to make sure the graphics object is properly disposed of, and I'm pretty sure your issue is going to disappear (though doing any real animation in Winforms is a lot more involved than that, so I'd also suggest you use something better suited for that, like WPF or UWP).

Comment: Why are you trying to move a rectangle? Is this for a form control animation? More context is needed for this question to be viable for an answer as there are different approaches depending on the use case of the interface.

Comment: @KieranDevlin Animations but not only, i like coding visualizations of any problem i can find, a very well know visualization would be the double pendulum or coding small 2D games like flappy bird. I mostly do that with Java (jswing or processing) and Javascript (p5.js).

Comment: @Luaan this  code at least on my side draws a rect on the top left corner and moves it towards the bottom right corner. Sorry if there are any errors on the code i never really used anything animated with C# and winforms at all.

Comment: @Stefan This looks more familiar to me as it comes closer to how p5 works.
Thank you !

Comment: @ŘenĞod In that case, WinForms control's aren't the best to do what you're trying to achieve as they aren't that performance oriented. Whats happening is that WinForms draws in the middle of when you are clearing the graphics context which shows the canvas as blank and then draws to it thus resulting in a flicker. Take a look at managing the buffer context yourself so that the graphics are only drawn once you tell it to, or look at a framework that is built for animation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-manually-manage-buffered-graphics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this in winforms. It support for graphics acceleration or optimizations is very limited.

Try `wpf` or `uwp` , it has a lot of features regarding to such animations supported out of the box.

See [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/animation-overview)

You could also go for a `DirectX` solution, but that would be even more of an overkill.

Do note that these frameworks typically use the `MVVM` pattern, in which you have a `Page` with the code behind, a `ViewModel` to act as a data-source and the `View` consisting of `XAML`.

This is a bit harder to handle than plain old `WinForms`, but if you a learning, and actually want to build nice looking applications it's definitely the way to go.

---

WPF animation come with a lot of base/helper classes, as can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation?view=netframework-4.8)

Here's an example, pure `XAML`:

```
<!-- just a container -->
<Canvas Background="Orange"> 
    <-- a canvas to apply the animation on -->
    <Canvas  x:Name="target" Background="Green"> 
        <!-- your rectangle -->
        <Rectangle Width="200" Height="100" Fill="Blue" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="4"/>
         <!-- the animation trigger -->
        <Canvas.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
                          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="target" 
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Left"
                                           From="0" To="100" 
                                           Duration="0:0:3"/>
                     </Storyboard>
                 </BeginStoryboard>
             </EventTrigger>
         </Canvas.Triggers>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: @ASh: thanks, I do agree, the initial answer was limited.... but an actual heads up would be nice. Although I did figure it out ;-) .. thanks again.